# Date time difference in moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, momentjs

- Set the value into local storage :

  ```
  $scope.SetLocalStorage('My-' + $rootScope.UserId, moment());
  ```
- Get the value form local storage :

  ```
  var dt = moment($scope.GetLocalStorage('My-' + $rootScope.UserId));
  ```
- To get the date time from the local storage :

  ```
  var dTime = moment(dt);
  ```

Here it shows invalid date :

[image]

I need the time difference in Hours :

```
var timeDifference = moment().diff(moment(dTime)), 'hours');
```

Issue : 'timeDifference' always gives **Nan**.

*Can you tell me why ? Any help would be highly appreciated.*

Libraries I have used: [Local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: I guess, $scope.GetLocalStorage('My-' + $rootScope.UserId) is ur moment() which is current time, why are you having moment('current time'), then again moment(momet('current time')) ?

Comment: @Nielarshi I need to store the current date time into the local storage and later time Where I need to check the difference of stored value and date time now ?

Comment: I think you have a problem with "'My-' + $rootScope.UserId" (key that you are using for storing in local storage). I dont see any error in the way you are doing. Check by giving some string key, instead of getting from rootScope.

Comment: var dTime = moment(dt); // is not required, var timeDifference = moment().diff(moment(dTime)), 'hours'); // this is also not required. Just you do var timeDifference = moment().diff(dt), 'hours');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moment()` returns an object, the local storage doesn't accept object. Parse into string before store the value

```
$scope.SetLocalStorage('My-' + $rootScope.UserId, JSON.stringify(moment()));
```

And when you use it use `JSON.parse` :

```
var dt = moment(JSON.parse($scope.GetLocalStorage('My-' + $rootScope.UserId)));
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that moment(), when using it that way, returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (same as doing `new Date().getTime()`). So now you have a number, which you're storing in the local storage, turning it into a string.

When you then construct a new `moment(someString)` object, it falls back to using Date for construction, which has a specific behavior since you passed it a string (it expects an ISO 8601 formatted string), which fails in your case.

The correct way is to store the correct representation in the local storage (which you can get by using `.format()`). You can leave the rest of the code the same.

```
$scope.SetLocalStorage('My-' + $rootScope.UserId, moment().format());
```

**EDIT:** This is (almost) the same as using `JSON.stringify(moment())` as R3tep suggested. Both solutions will turn the current time into an ISO 8601 representation in order to store it properly as a string so you can use either one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your lengthy explanation.